# Is there any problem with this nested while loop?

Tags: c++

I want a odd number greater than 7. But when i enter 66 the nested while loop doesn't execute and doesn't ask to re enter. is there any problem with logic?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fuserinput(int);

int main()
{
    int num=0;
    fuserinput(num);
}

void fuserinput(int num)
{
    cout<<"Enter a odd number greater than 7 : ";
    cin>>num;

    while((num<7))
    {
        cout<<"enter number greator than 7 : ";
        cin>>num;
        while(num%2==0)
        {
          cout<<"You have entered even number please reenter : ";
          cin>>num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(num < 7)` - if `num` is valued `66`, what would the condition expression `num < 7` result in? What would be the effect of this result regarding conditionally entering the body of the of the `while` loop?

Comment: Why does `fuserinput` bother to take an argument when the first thing the function does is overwriting that input/argument with user input.?

Comment: If you have entered 66, you never reached the inner loop since it does not meet the first loop condition

Comment: Note that by separating the tests, you create the possibility for the user to pass each test with different numbers.  If you want the user to enter a number that is both odd and greater than seven, your loop has to repeat both tests every time a number is entered.

Comment: how i get a odd number greator than 7 from user and if he enter a wrong input by mistake then program asks the user to re enter

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to keep the loop untill the number is greater than 7 and odd, right?

your first loop will never enter if you enter a number greater than 7. You can use a do...while statement to make that code always enter on the loop at least one, than you will know for sure that the code is always get to the inner loop at least once.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fuserinput(int);

int main()
{
    int num=0;
    fuserinput(num);
}

void fuserinput(int num)
{
    cout<<"Enter a odd number greater than 7 : ";
    cin>>num;

    do {
        cout<<"enter number greator than 7 : ";
        cin>>num;
        while(num%2==0)
        {
          cout<<"You have entered even number please reenter : ";
          cin>>num;
        }
    } while((num<7));
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what if i use && in the first while loop without making two different tests

Comment: @Subhan The way, you write the code depend how you want to do validation and display to the user. Do you want to prioritize one message over the other? Should you display all problems or to repeat last failed check until it pass then make the other check until it pass...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a bit more to it. You want to loop continually until you receive the desired input. However with every read, you must test each of the error states (`eof(), bad(), fail()` as well as validating your input is within the valid range you want, and odd.

There is nothing difficult about it, but you must take it step-by-step and remember to empty all characters that remain in your input buffer unread -- that could bite you on your next attempted read. You could do:

```
#include <limits>
...
void fuserinput (int& num)
{
    num = 0;

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */

        cout << "Enter a odd number greator than 7 : "; /* prompt */

        if (!(cin >> num)) {    /* handle all error states */
            if (cin.eof() || cin.bad()) {   /* eofbit or badbit */
                cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
                return;
            }
            else if (cin.fail()) {      /* if failbit */
                cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
                cin.clear();            /* clear failbit */
                /* extract any characters that remain unread */
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        else {  /* on succesful read */
            /* extract any characters that remain unread */
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            /* validate that num is in range and odd */
            if (num > 7 && num % 2 == 1)
                break;  /* good input break read loop */
            else
                cerr << "error: num <= 7 or not odd.\n"
        }
    }
}
```

(**note** I would suggest changing the return to a meaningful type like `int` and since you want `> 7 plus odd`, you can return `-1` to indicate failure in the calling function)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use nested loops in this case. One way would be something like that:

- Do in a loop:

  - Read a number
  - If that number if smaller that 7 print a message
  - Else if the number is even print the second message
  - Else exit the loop

A better way would be to use a function that validate the number and print the message. That way you could do something like:

```
do
{
    cin >> num;
} while (!ValidateNumber(num));
```